# Updating a variable that is storing a state using MutableStateFlow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

```
@HiltViewModel
class UserViewModel @Inject constructor(private val userRepo: UserRepo): ViewModel() {
private val _state = MutableStateFlow(User())
val state: StateFlow<User> = _state

fun getUser(name: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        userRepo.getUser(name)
            .collect {
                _state.value = it
            }
    }
}
}
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun UserScreen(
    onNextClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    val vm: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        //verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        // Text above the text box
        Text(
            text = "Who are you?",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp)
        )

        // Text box for entering name
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = name,
            onValueChange = { name = it },
            label = { Text("Name") },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        
        Button(
            onClick = {
                onNextClick()
                vm.getUser(name)
            },
            enabled = name.isNotEmpty()
            ) {
            Text(text = "Next")
        }
```

Repo

```
class UserRepo @Inject constructor(private val database: AppDataBase) {

    private val userDao = database.userDao()

    suspend fun getUser(name: String): Flow<User> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            userDao.getUser(name)
        }
    }
}
```

screen where information should display on load

```
@Composable
fun UserInfoScreen() {

    val vm: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val user = vm.state.collectAsState()

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
        Text(text = "Hello ${user.value.name}")
    }
}
```

I have two variables and I'm trying to update them using my function.

This is being implemented in my compose button on a user screen. Once the button is pressed, it passes the name through the function and query's information about the User. The next screen is supposed to display this User information and it being `collectAsState` on that screen. The function shows that the user information is being collected, but the variables aren't being updated.

I've tried using the function as a variable but it kept coming back as a Unit. I've tried adding a loading state but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Comment: Hey,  can you provide more information about the repository and the screen where the User information is supposed to be displayed?

Comment: Updated the post with the repo and screens. I'm not so concerned about the loading state as much as I am about updating the variable. I'm trying to rap my head around this simple concept.

Comment: The answer was that I was creating two separate instances of the viewModel. I have to move to viewModel to the root of the app composables which was in my MainActivity and instantiate it there.

Answer (score 0):

Modify variable and function definition like this in ViewModel to enable loading state:

```
// ViewModel
class UserViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _userState = MutableStateFlow<User?>(null)
    val userState: StateFlow<User?> = _userState

    private val _loadingState = MutableStateFlow<Boolean>(false)
    val loadingState: StateFlow<Boolean> = _loadingState

    fun getUser(name: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _loadingState.value = true // Set loading state to true

                val user = userRepo.getUser(name)
                _userState.value = user
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Handle error
            } finally {
                _loadingState.value = false // Set loading state back to false
            }
        }
    }
}

// Composable function
@Composable
fun UserScreen(viewModel: UserViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val userState by viewModel.userState.collectAsState()
    val loadingState by viewModel.loadingState.collectAsState()

    // Your UI code here, using userState and loadingState
    // You can use a loading indicator based on loadingState



    Button(
        onClick = {
            viewModel.getUser("someUserName")
        }
    ) {
        Text("Fetch User")
    }
}
```

If this doesn't help out then please provide `UserRepo` code block and `UI` code block for better answer!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the Dao functions that have a suspend modifier must not return a deferred/async type (such as a Flow). In your use case, you must change the return type of the `getUser()` function to a nullable `User?`. I assume your implementation of the `UserDao` is something like this:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getUser(name: String): User? // Changed from Flow<User>

    @Upsert
    suspend fun saveUser(user: User)

}
```

The same applies to the `UserRepo`:

```
class UserRepo @Inject constructor(database: AppDataBase) {

    private val userDao = database.userDao()

    suspend fun getUser(name: String): User? /* Changed from Flow<User> */ {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            userDao.getUser(name)
        }
    }

    suspend fun saveUser(user: User) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            userDao.saveUser(user)
        }
    }

}
```

To implement a loading state and error handling, you can declare a `Boolean` state in the `UserViewModel` and update the states using a try/catch/finally blocks like the following:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class UserViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userRepo: UserRepo
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _userState = MutableStateFlow(User())
    val userState = _userState.asStateFlow()

    private val _isLoadingState = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isLoadingState = _isLoadingState.asStateFlow()

    fun getUser(name: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {

                // Start the loading by updating
                // the [isLoadingState] to true.
                _isLoadingState.update { true }

                // An artificial delay enough to keep the
                // [isLoadingState] true for at least one second.
                delay(1_000L)

                // Get the user from the repository and update
                // the [userState] with the new value if not null.
                userRepo.getUser(name)?.let { user -> _userState.update { user } }

            } catch (e: Exception) {

                // Handle an occurred exception.
                println("UserViewModel: $e")

            } finally {

                // Stop the loading by updating
                // the [isLoadingState] to false.
                _isLoadingState.update { false }

            }
        }
    }

    fun saveUser(name: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userRepo.saveUser(
                user = User(name = name)
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Since the `UserViewModel` is used in both `UserScreen` and `UserInfoScreen`, you can make a single top-level instance of the viewmodel and share it with both screens.

I assume you have a navigation host or something like this:

```kotlin
val navController = rememberNavController()
val userViewModel = hiltViewModel<UserViewModel>()

NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "user_screen_route"
) {
  
    composable(route = "user_screen_route") {

        UserScreen(
            onGetUser = userViewModel::getUser,
            onNextClick = { navController.navigate("user_info_screen_route") }
        )

    }

    composable(route = "user_info_screen_route") {

        val isLoading by userViewModel.isLoadingState.collectAsState()
        val user by userViewModel.state.collectAsState()

        UserInfoScreen(
            isLoading = isLoading,
            user = user
        )

    }

}
```

Finally, to reflect on the changes, the `UserScreen` and `UserInfoScreen` must be modified as well:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun UserScreen(
    onGetUser: (String) -> Unit, // A callback to get the user.
    onNextClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {

    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        //verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        // Text above the text box
        Text(
            text = "Who are you?",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp)
        )

        // Text box for entering name
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = name,
            onValueChange = { name = it },
            label = { Text("Name") },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )

        Button(
            onClick = {
                onGetUser(name)
                onNextClick()
            },
            enabled = name.isNotEmpty()
        ) {
            Text(text = "Next")
        }

    }

}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun UserInfoScreen(
    isLoading: Boolean,
    user: User
) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        // Show the content if the [isLoading] state is false.
        AnimatedVisibility(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            visible = !isLoading
        ) {

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            ) {

                Text(text = "Hello ${user.name}")

            }

        }

        // Show a loading indicator if the [isLoading] state is true.
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = isLoading
        ) {

            CircularProgressIndicator()

        }

    }

}
```

Happy coding!